# Date formatting to MM/DD/YYYY in LWC datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

How do we format the date in datatable like `MM/DD/YYYY` in LWC data table.

In my datatable column type is defined as `date`,  value display in table as 
`Jan 10, 2020`. Expecting in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

`{ label: "Start Date", fieldName: "Program_Start_Date__c", type: "date" },`

**I gone through the LWC data table Documentation:**

Displays a date and time based on the locale using lightning-formatted-date-time. 
 
Displaying Date and Time Using Type Attributes. 
 **Type Attribute:** day, era, hour, hour12, minute, month, second, timeZone, timeZoneName, weekday, year

```
typeAttributes: {
 day: 'numeric',
month: 'short',
year: 'numeric',
hour: '2-digit',
minute: '2-digit',
second: '2-digit',
hour12: true
}
```

Still not works, Can anyone Please help me on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) internally uses [lightning-formatted-date](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/example) to output date field.

To output, the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format set the type attribute to

```
typeAttributes: {
    day: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    year: "numeric"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it's Worked