# Lightning Web Component datatable - date time formatting

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, datetime, formatting

I'm creating a LWC with datatable that shows some of the key record values.
I have just one issue - regarding the date/time formatting.

For some reason, the field is shown as:
[image]

My goal is to show it as follow:
[image]

I tried everything, but nothing seems to help here ..
This is my code:

HTML

```
<template>
  <lightning-card> 
    <lightning-datatable class="slds-table_header-fixed_container slds-scrollable_x slds-border_top"
                            data={data}
                            columns={columns}
                            key-field="id"
                            hide-checkbox-column="true"
                            show-row-number-column="true">
    </lightning-datatable>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
const columns = [
            {label: 'Created Date', 
            fieldName: 'CreatedDate', 
            sortable: "true",
            type: "date",
            typeAttributes:{
                hour: "2-digit",
                minute: "2-digit",
                day: "2-digit",
                month: "2-digit",
                year: "numeric"}}];

export default class FormattedDateTimeDateTime extends LightningElement {
  columns = columns;
  data = [{"CreatedDate":"2021-05-17T14:04:23.000Z"}];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: The issue is that the "order" or display of the date and time is controlled by the User's Locale setting (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.admin_supported_date_time_format.htm&type=5)

Comment: Got it. And if I want to change the format without changing the user locale ? 
My goal is to show '/' between the dates and not '.'

Comment: Check this [SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301553/date-formatting-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-lwc-datatable). This might work for you.

Comment: Tried it .. unfortunately no luck

Comment: @Omnia you would have to write your own table to get the formatting you are looking for

Comment: You might get away with creating a specialized table with a custom type. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) (search for "Creating Custom Data Types").